# fget(c) - scanning the next character while saving the previous

Tags: c, file-io, fgetc

I'm trying to create a program that reads a file and counts the number of words beginning with `'a'`.

My idea is to:

- Scan a character, see if it is alphabetic.
- If it isn't then I will know the next character is a new word
- Scan the next character to check if it is either `'a'` or `'A'`

What I'd like to know is if there is a simple way to scan the next character using `fgetc()` while still remembering the previous.

Something like:

```
char letter;
int aCount = 0;

while ((letter = fgetc(testFile)) != EOF) {

    if (isalpha(letter) == false && ('nextCharacter' == 'a' || 'nextCharacter' == 'A')) {

        aCount++; 
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what variables are for: remember a value. But `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char` for a good reason! Please read the man pages of functions.

Comment: amey, it's an example, where 'nextcharacter' would be a variable containing the next character  of a found word

Comment: the code isn't valid, as he said "Something like";

Comment: For storing why not use an array and iterate over it .

Comment: So I need to declare a new variable called, say 'prevChar' and add implement something like if islapha(letter) == false { prevChar == letter } and move on from there?

Comment: Hint: `lastLetter =letter;`

Comment: Ok thank you very much everybody, I think understand now. You help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your code:

- bytes read from the file should be stored into an `int` variable to accomodate for `EOF` and all unsigned char values.  If you store it into a `char` variable, you cannot reliably check for `EOF`.
- you should save the previous byte to test for word start, and use `letter` to check if the current word starts with `'a'` or `'A'`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int prev = ' '; // pretend there is a non letter before the first byte.
int c;
int aCount = 0;

while ((c = fgetc(testFile)) != EOF) {

    if (!isalpha(prev) && (c == 'a' || c == 'A')) {
        aCount++; 
    }
    prev = c;
}
printf("there are %d words starting with 'a'\n", aCount);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think my main problem was I thought fgetc() returned a char not an int.

Comment: `int c; while ((c = fgetc(testFile)) != EOF) { ... }` is a very idiomatic way to parse a stream byte by byte.